# Qt4 QNetworkManager Hangs

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to write an application using QNetworkManager.  I have simplified the code down to the problem.  The following code hangs, and I have no idea why:

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "post.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   QApplication app(argc, argv);
   post("http://google.com/search", "q=test");
   return app.exec();
}
```

post.h:

```
#ifndef _H_POST
#define _H_POST

#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkRequest>

class post : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT

   public:
      post(QString URL, QString data);

   public slots:
      void postFinished(QNetworkReply* reply);

   protected:
      QNetworkAccessManager *connection;

};

#endif
```

post.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QUrl>
#include "post.h"

post::post(QString URL, QString data) {
   connection = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
   connect(connection, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(postFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
   connection->post(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(URL)), data.toAscii());
}

void post::postFinished(QNetworkReply*) {
   qApp->exit(0);
}
```

Some Googling shows it may be because I have everything on one thread, but I have no idea how to change that in Qt... none of the network examples show this.

Comment: Does it hang in connect->post or in app.exec?

Comment: app.exec
it seems that post::postFinished never gets called

Comment: Which version of Qt are you running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried it with the same results. The problem is that you are creating the post object by only calling the constructor. Since you are not specifying an object it is getting destroyed right away (to check this create a destructor and see when it gets called.)

try:

```
post p("http://google.com/search","q=test");
```

Then your slot gets called.

Comment: It's a valid pointer, and ->rawHeaderList() returns an empty list.

Comment: Nice catch... I completely skimmed over that part trying to get to the class code for post.